# OpenCV 2.4.9 and CUDA 6.5

Tags: opencv, cmake

I recently upgraded to CUDA 6.5, and I recompiled succefully OpenCV 2.4.9 on Ubuntu 14.04.

However when I recompiled my project using OpenCV and cmake, I got the following configuration error:

```
-- GCC detected, adding compile flags
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find CUDA: Found unsuitable version "6.5", but required is exact
  version "6.0" (found /usr/local/cuda-6.5)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:313 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:806 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake:215 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/andrey/Data/Projects/Groups_code/Lulu/build-Ubuntu/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

How to fix this one? Do I need to reinstall cmake, or upgrade Modules file in cmake?

Answer (score 1):

Try delete cmake cache.
"File"->"Delete Cache". Then "Configure" , "Generate" as usual.

Comment: I create a new build directory and run cmake ../src. It still has the same error.

Comment: I had the same issue, I solved it (in GUI) by deleting the cache, then set check box "Advanced", and in CUDA group change all cuda versions to 6.5.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when OpenCV is built with a certain version of CUDA it specifies that in the file `/usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake`. If you have changed your version of CUDA *after* you built OpenCV then rebuilding OpenCV with the new CUDA version should fix this. That will basically rewrite the new version to `/usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake`.

In addition, it seems that you are calling `find_package(CUDA)` after calling `find_package(OpenCV)`. That enforces cmake to look for the version of CUDA with which OpenCV was built. If you call `find_package(CUDA)` before `find_package(OpenCV)` you will likely see something like:

```
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda-6.5 (found version "6.5") 
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake:222 (message):
  OpenCV static library was compiled with CUDA 6.0 support.  Please, use the
  same version or rebuild OpenCV with CUDA 6.5
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (find_package)
```

OpenCV source has been changing over the years with different versions of CUDA and so a version mismatch there can cause things to break. So the recommended way to fix this is to rebuild OpenCV.